# Determining the distribution of data within the cluster in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to examine the distribution of my data within the cluster. I know how to find out what data is inside each partition. However, I haven't figured out how to find out the distribution of the data within the cluster.

Does a method exist in Spark to find out which rows or how many rows of a data frame are on a particular node within the cluster?

Or alternatively, is there a method to map from the partition ID to the executor ID?

Kind regards

Comment: for what reason?